# Find a stardard deviation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean

$$N=30 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{30}x_i=120 \\
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{30}x_i^{2}=750\\
$$

Find a standard deviation of x:

$$
\bar{x}=\frac{120}{30}=4 \\
sd=\sqrt[]{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^{2}}{N}}=\sqrt[]{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^{2}-2\bar{x}x_i+\bar{x}^{2})}{N}}=\sqrt[]{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{2}-2n\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+n\bar{x}^{2}}{N}}=\sqrt[]{\frac{750-2*30*4*120+30*{4}^{2}}{30}}=30.1$$

But in the textbook the answer is 4

Answer (score 1):

There is another formula for the variance of a random variable derived from the first and second moments.

$Var(X)=E((X-\mu)^2)=E(X^2)-E(\mu)^2=E(X^2)-\mu^2$.

As it turns out, you have all the information you need to estimate this.

Comment: Oh my god, I forgot about that formula. Thanks. But it gives a different answer (27)

Comment: @PHPUseless Are you sure about that? Is that the result of the variance of $X$ or the standard deviation of $X$?

Comment: yeah, sd=sqrt(27), it is about 5, but the answer is 4. And what's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: @PHPUseless $SD(X)=\sqrt{750/30-(120/30)^2}=3$ for me.

Comment: why should we divide 750 by N=30?

Comment: @PHPUseless To get the expected value of $E(X^2)$, same as for $E(X)$.